# Solr with large integer lists

Tags: solr, schema, solrcloud

**Is solr able to handle large lists of integers within documents?**

Lookups will be exclusively by exact match. Most documents would have ~100  list entries, some would be ~1k and < 10 with up to 25k.

Addition: **What is the best schema for large lists?**

My idea was an indexed, not stored, multivalued field. The type could be TrieLongField with precisionStep="0". Another idea was to store the data as plain text with a word tokenizer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a multivalued integer field, this should give good performance:

```
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" 
      positionIncrementGap="0" 
      precisionStep="0" 
      omitNorms="true" 
      omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"          
      multiValued="true" stored="false"
  />
```

Comment: sounds good, thanks! do you have experience if solr behaves wired with this kind of fields in the documents? i.e. much more ram usage or similar effects.

Comment: I changed my mind, you loose some performance converting the int to a dictionary key if you store in plain text, specially if you have very many possible integer values. :) I have never done what you propose but SOLR should work well... it's easier than actually searching text :)